# bash: get only double dash or single dash options

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

In a linux bash script, I want to have two lists of arguments: one are those started with single dash and the other those started with double dash. For example:

```
   script -a 1 --b=3 -c 7 --d=8
```

Then it can return them in two group variables:

```
  group1 : -a 1 -c 7
  group2 : --b=3 --d=8
```

I know that `$@` holds a list of all arguments. I don't know whether I should iterate them and make them distinct or there are easier solutions. This is my try:

```
g1=""
g2=""
for i in $@; do
   echo $i
   if [[ $i == --* ]]; then
      g1="${g1} $i"
   else
      g2="${g2} $i"
   fi 
done
echo $g1
echo $g2
```

regardless of its accuracy, it says:

```
test.sh: 5: [[: not found
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: @anubhava I did

Comment: @tink I described more

Comment: `[[` is a bashism; you seem to be using `sh`.

Comment: @tink so what should I use instead?

Comment: Instead of `sh` or instead of `[[`?

Comment: instead of [[, I used single one [ and got the same error while I use single one in my other scripts

Comment: I strongly suggest that you test your script with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) ... make sure you give it the right `#!/bin/XXX` on the first line.

Comment: The error message indicates that you are not using bash, so first of all, I would run the script under bash (i.e. `bash PATH/TO/SCRIPT`). Then you should quote `"$@"` to keep spaces in the command arguments intact. Finally, once you switched to bash, you have arrays, so I would make `g1` and `g2` an array. If you don't, you will run again into problems when an argument passed to your script contains a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case/esac` to facilitate the option parsing instead of a `ìf`. And use the shebang (`#!`) to choose the shell you want to use. I also added a case to manage parameters without options:

```bash
#!/bin/sh


g1=""
g2=""
for i in $@
do

   echo $i
   case $i in
       
       # -- option
       --*) g1="${g1} $i"; g=1;;
       
       # - option
       -*) g2="${g2} $i"; g=2;;
       
       # Parameter 
       *) p=$i
          if [ "$g" = 1 ]
          then
            g1="${g1} $p"
            g=0
          elif [ "$g" = 2 ]
          then
            g2="${g2} $p"
            g=0
          else
            others="$others $p"
          fi
      ;;
 
   esac

done
echo g1=$g1
echo g2=$g2
echo others=$others
```

Example of runs:

```
$ ./t.sh -o opt --t -h --h --p param param2
-o
opt
--t
-h
--h
--p
param
param2
g1= --t --h --p param
g2= -o opt -h
others= param2
$ ./t.sh file -o --t --p param
file
-o
--t
--p
param
g1= --t --p param
g2= -o
others= file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may better use shell array to hold 2 different set of arguments. With few fixes this script should address it:

```bash
g1=()
g2=()

for i; do
   if [[ $i == '--'* ]]; then
      g1+=( "$i" )
   else
      g2+=( "$i" )
   fi 
done

echo "group1: ${g1[@]}"
echo "group2: ${g2[@]}"
```

**Output:**

```bash
group1: --b=3 --d=8
group2: -a 1 -c 7
```

Comment: thanks, by adding `!#\bin\sh` and make my file executable, my error resolved and my solution works. In your case, `group2` must include `-a 1 -c 7`

Answer (score 1):

**I believe using enhanced `getopt` works best.**

Although I would guess it's omnipresent, I still like to set a fallback alternative.

```
# Fetch getopt version
getopt --test > /dev/null 

# If returns 4 parse with getopt
# Otherwise means it's a version we don't like
if [[ $? -ne 4 ]]; then
  printf "warning: \`getopt --test\` did not return 4...\ndefaulting to std handling...\n"
else
  # A colon after the option means an additional arg is expected
  _longopts="src:,dest:,config:,delete,update,interactive,verbose,version,help"
  _options="s:d:f:DuIvVh"

  # Parse command line arguments using getopt
  PARSED=$(getopt --options=$_options --longoptions=$_longopts --name "$0" -- "$@")
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    exit 1
  else
    # Set getopt output
    eval set -- "$PARSED"
  fi
fi

# Parse command arguments
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  # Shift makes you parse next argument as $1.
  # Shift n makes you move n arguments ahead.
  case $1 in
    -s|--src)
      # Remove any amount of trailing slashes
      _trimmed_s="${2%%+(/)}"
      # Source files
      IFS=' ' read -r -a sources <<< "$_trimmed_s"
      shift 2
      ;;
    -d|--dest)
      # Remove any amount of trailing slashes
      _trimmed_d="${2%%+(/)}"
      # Destination path
      IFS=' ' read -r -a destination <<< "$_trimmed_d"
      shift 2
      ;;
    -f|--config)
      IFS=' ' read -r -a config_file <<< "$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    -D|--delete)
      # Delete files
      delete=1
      shift
      ;;
    -u|--update)
      # Update files
      update=1
      shift
      ;;
    -I|--interactive)
      # Prompt user for actions
      interactive=1
      shift
      ;;
    -v|--verbose)
      # Print more stuff
      let verbose++
      shift
      ;;
    -V|--version)
      # Print version number
      echo 0.000000001
      shift
      ;;
    -h|--help)
      # Print help
      echo huh... sorry.
      shift
      ;;
    --)
      shift
      break
      ;;
    -*|--*)
      echo "${0}: invalid option -- '${1}'"
      exit 1
      ;;
    *)
      positional_args+=("$1") # Save positional args
      shift
      ;;
  esac
done

# If getopt wasn't used
if [ -z "$_options" ]; then
  # Restore positional arguments
  set -- "${positional_args[@]}"
fi

# Free arguments are now set as $@ 
# Can be accessed later on
```

This code lets you use pretty much any sort of argument style (e.g: `--opt=value -a --test this_value free arguments here -oOutfileTouchingArgument ...`). If you want to separate short and long options (god knows why) you can easily do this:

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  case $1 in
    -s)
      # Do whatever you do with short options
      shift
      ;;
    --long)
      # This is a long option
      shift
      ;;
  esac
done
```